# Set atom to open files only on double click

Tags: atom-editor

I have recently switched from sublime to atom, 
I love the git integration there is something that bothers me though. 
In sublime single click lets you view the file but it doesn't open it only double clicks opens it. I want to configure the same behaviour on atom is that possible ?

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is hidden as an option in the **tabs** package (installed by default). Enable the "Use Preview Tabs" option in this package or add this to your `config.cson`:

```
"*":
  tabs:
    usePreviewTabs: true
```